# How can I fix this sql syntax error using visual basic 6.0?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm receiving Syntax Error on this SQL query.

```
s2 = "select * from Seats where train name like '" & trains.lbl4.Caption & "' and train no like " & trains.lbl3.Caption
```

Please help me identify the syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Seats where [train name] like '" & trains.lbl4.Caption & "%' and [train no] like '" & trains.lbl3.Caption & "%'"
```

this should do it

If you have exact values to match on then use this select statement:

```
select * from Seats where [train name] ='" & trains.lbl4.Caption & "' and [train no] = '" & trains.lbl3.Caption & "'"
```

Comment: why is the "%" being used ? the code has worked.jus need to know why the "%" is used

Comment: the % symbol is a wildcard symbol. what it means is give me anything that matches after what I type in. So lets say I am looking up a customer by last name. The last name is 'smith' but all I know is I want everyone with the last name that start with 'smi' so I use a wild character and do a search like 'smi%' and it will give me back everything that starts with 'smi'. If you don't want to use like then use "=" and get rid of the wildcard characters

Comment: To note, with the like command you can use wild card characters before and after your search criteria